# Calculate memory accesses

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, cpu-architecture, machine-code

xor dword [0x301a80], 0x12345

How many memory access when we know the op code and addressing mode is 2 bytes?

If I understand correctly, even thought it is 0x12345, this is acctually still 4 bytes and we cant attach it to 0x301a80, right?

So we have here:

2 + 4 + 4 bytes (And not 2 + 3.5 + 2.5 = 8) which is 4 memory access.

Am I think right?

Answer (score 2):

The total instruction size is 10 bytes (in 32-bit mode).  That takes probably 0 to 2 I-cache accesses on a modern x86 to fetch in aligned 16-byte accesses.  (0 if it hits in the uop cache).

When executed, it does a 4-byte load + a 4-byte store (on an aligned address), which should be a total of 2 data accesses on CPUs other than 386SX (16-bit bus).  These can probably hit in cache unless the memory region is uncacheable.

More loads could be generated by page walks on a TLB miss for that address, if paging is enabled.  (And if running inside a VM, both guest and host page tables could be involved with nested page tables.  It would be vastly more expensive overall if it #PF page-faulted, but counting the work an OS might do is silly.)

If you're wondering about the total number of bytes touched by an instruction, see [Do x86 instructions require their own encoding as well as all of their arguments to be present in memory at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60968748) which talks about instruction + data being in memory at once for forward progress to be possible.  But it seems you're counting *number of accesses*, not the footprint of the bytes accessed.  But you haven't said by what microarchitecture.  x86 spans huge range from the first 32-bit capable CPU that could run this instruction (386) up to modern x86 with wide pipelines that try to do a lot in parallel.

---

If you mean "opcode and addressing mode" = opcode + *ModRM* byte then yes that's 2 bytes.  Most people would consider "the addressing mode" to include the 4-byte `disp32` as well as the ModRM (that signals which addressing mode is used and the presence of displacement bytes).  The immediate is also 4 bytes.  So I think your "2+4+4" size calculation is adding up pieces of the total instruction and not counting data accesses.  And yes, that 10 bytes total is correct.

**Use an assembler to see instruction sizes.**  e.g. `nasm -felf32 -l/dev/stdout foo.asm` with a file containing that instruction:

```
$ cat > foo.asm   # then paste your instruction
xor dword [0x301a80], 0x12345
<control-d for EOF>
$ nasm -felf32 -l/dev/stdout foo.asm
     1 00000000 8135801A3000452301-     xor dword [0x301a80], 0x12345
     1 00000009 00
$ objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o   # nicer disassembly format, not line-wrapped
...
   0:   81 35 80 1a 30 00 45 23 01 00   xor    DWORD PTR ds:0x301a80,0x12345
```

- In 32-bit mode: a 10 byte instruction: opcode + modrm + disp32 + imm32.
- In 64-bit mode: 11 bytes (+SIB to encode the 32-bit absolute address; the shorter encoding was re-purposed for RIP-relative).
- In 16-bit mode: 12 bytes: 66 and 67 operand and address-size prefixes in front of the same opcode + modrm + disp32 + imm32 as 32-bit mode.

x86 machine code can only do `imm8` or `imm32` for an instruction with 32-bit operand-size.  You can see that in the manual for [xor](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor) specifically.  So yes, `0x12345` takes a full 32-bit dword immediate, not 2.5 or 3 bytes.  x86 machine code is a byte stream, but there are only a few fixed sizes for the pieces any given instruction is built from.  Same deal for the displacement in the addressing mode.

---

I don't understand how you're getting 4 "accesses" for the 2 + 4 + 4 = 10 byte total size you calculated.  If you're just talking about loading the instruction from memory, are you picturing that it's a 1-byte load of the opcode, then 1 byte for the modrm, then 4 bytes each for the disp32 and imm32?  Maybe not, since you didn't write it as `1 + 1 + 4 + 4`.

In any case, that's not how CPUs work.  Old x86 CPUs have a prefetch buffer that they fill with bus-width aligned accesses, then decode from that buffer.  They can't just load an unaligned dword from memory with a single access.  386SX with its 16-bit bus might have taken 4 total accesses to fetch this instruction, or 6 if it started at an odd address.

In modern CPUs with caches, instruction fetch from L1i cache happens in blocks of 16, aligned I think.   (On CPUs since Intel P6: https://agner.org/optimize/)  So this instruction might be fetched as part of 1 or 2 I-cache accesses.  (2 if it's split across a 16-byte boundary).

**Or it might not need to get fetched at all**: the uop cache caches decoded instructions, not x86 machine code, so with a uop-cache hit this instruction can run without any code fetch from memory.  (Intel Sandybridge-family and AMD Zen have uop caches; Intel since Core 2 has a loop buffer that can still avoid actual fetch from L1i cache, and skip some or all of the decode work.)  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ has a good deep-dive into SnB-family.

---

**That leaves 2 accesses: dword data load, dword data store.**  The address is 16-byte aligned so a dword load + store is never going to split into multiple accesses.  But it's not an atomic RMW (no `lock` prefix) so the load and store are separate memory accesses to the same 4 bytes.

A dword memory access is guaranteed atomic on x86 since 486 ([Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)), so any non-ancient CPU will do each of those accesses as a single operation (to cache, or to memory if that's an uncacheable address).

Or this could run on a 386SX where each dword data access happens as two 16-bit bus operations.  Full 32-bit bus 386 chips also existed which would do full dword load or store as a single access, like later CPUs.