# Minimum number of frames for correct execution of processes

Tags: assembly, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

What is the minimum number of frames for correct execution of processes on a processor with instructions of type (and why):

register instruction, memory-operation
register instruction, register
memory-operation instruction, register
register instruction, memory-operation

For example:

```
ADD REG8 [0xcafe]
MOV [0xdead], [0xbeef]
SUB REG1, REG2
MUL [0xfefe], REG9
```

Comment: What ISA is this?  Does it allow unaligned memory operands that can span two pages?  Can a single instruction span two pages?  For the x86 version of this question, worst-case number of physical pages (page frames) required to make forward progress, see [Do x86 instructions require their own encoding as well as all of their arguments to be present in memory at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60968748) - 6 pages of user-space code/data, plus the page-table pages, because x86 has some instructions that access two separate memory locations, and those can be 2 bytes split across pages.

Comment: This sure sounds like someone is asking us to do their homework.