# Is calling `add` on a memory location faster than calling it on a register and then moving the value?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, micro-optimization

What's faster:

```
add DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],1
```

or

```
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
 add    eax,1
 mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

I've seen the second code generated by a compiler, so maybe calling `add` on a register is much faster?

Comment: likely slower but implementation defined...

Comment: You have likely seen it generated by a compiler with optimizations disabled...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both decode to the same amount of back-end uops, but the memory-destination `add` gets those uops through the front-end in fewer fused-domain uops on modern Intel/AMD CPUs.

On Intel CPUs, `add [mem], imm` decodes to a micro-fused load+add and a micro-fused store-address+store-data, so 2 total fused-domain uops for the front-end.  AMD CPUs always keep memory operands grouped with the ALU operation without calling it "micro-fusion", it's just how they've always worked.
(https://agner.org/optimize/ and [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter)).

---

The first way **doesn't leave the value in a register**, so you couldn't use it as part of `++a` if the value of the expression was used.  Only for the the side-effect on memory.

---

**Using `[rbp - 4]` and incrementing a local in memory smells like un-optimized / debug-mode code, which you should *not* be looking at for what's efficient.**  Optimized code typically uses `[rsp +- constant]` to address locals, and (unless the variable is `volatile`) wouldn't be just storing it back into memory again right away.

[Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) - compiling in debug mode, aka `-O0` (the default) compiles each C statement separately, and treats every variable sort of like `volatile`, which is totally horrible.

**See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for how to get compilers to make asm that's interesting to look at.**  Write a function that takes args and returns a value so it can do something without optimizing away or propagating constants into `mov eax, constant_result`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to a register probably *is* faster (since the registers are on-chip) but, since you have to load and store the data anyway, you're unlikely to see an improvement.

The long-winded approach might even be *slower* since there may be opportunities for the CPU to optimise the shorter code. In addition, the shorter code *may* have atomicity for the read/modify/write, depending on how you code it. It certainly won't waste the `eax` register.

Bottom line, the longer code is unlikely to be enough of an improvement (if any) to justify the readability hit.

But you don't have to guess (or even ask us) - the chip manufacturers provide copious details on the timings of instructions. For example, [Intel's optimisation manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#optimization).

Comment: Re: atomicity: only with respect to interrupts, therefore only wrt. other code running *on that core*.  [Taking a semaphore must be atomic. Is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358907).  In C++ we could say it's atomic wrt. a signal handler in the same thread.

Comment: @Peter, that was why I included the weasel words "depending on how you code it" :-) My understanding is that the `lock` prefix on an `inc` opcode on memory will buslock so that other cores don't try to use the value mid change. I could be wrong, of course, it's been a while since I coded that close to the metal.

Comment: Right, to make it atomic wrt. other cores you need `lock inc [mem]` or `lock add [mem], 1`.  If the memory isn't split across cache lines, though, the core only needs to hang onto MESI exclusive ownership of that one line (a "cache lock") from the load to the store; no need to bother other cores that are accessing different lines.  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) has an overview of details.